# Firebase deploy error on public key / directory

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am building an IOS app using Firebase. I have an error when I try to deploy 
**"Error: Specified public directory does not exist, can't deploy hosting"**
I have been following the hosting guide here  [Guide Link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html) But being new learner, I am not understanding what should I put in `firebase.json`

So my code in `firebase.json`

```
{
  "firebase": "xxxxxx", //(my app name)
  "public": "/usr/local", //(I am not sure what should i put in here)
  "ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"**.*",
"**/node_modules/**"
]
}
```

I am not sure what should I put in `"public"` property. I think that is the reason why I get the error. I don't understand what **public directory** mean in here.

Comment: Have a look at the [Firebase Features](https://www.firebase.com/features.html) page. When you're building an iOS app using Firebase, you are most likely using the Firebase Database and possible Firebase Authentication. Firebase Hosting is a service to host your web site, which you can deploy with `firebase deploy`. What do you expect to happen when you run `firebase deploy`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I m not sure but I'm expecting the firebase dashboard-hosting will be change and shown the JSON file ?

Comment: Running `firebase deploy` deploys a web site. If you're building an iOS app, you're not building a web application. What's your goal here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Easily deploy and host your app's static assets (HTML, CSS,
>   JavaScript, etc) with our production-grade hosting service. All of
>   your content is served over HTTPS and backed by a global CDN.

It cleary states only static thing is expected to be hosted.

In `"public"` you are supposed to put dist (distribution) folder distination, In web apps Its a folder that contains all assets to keep app **up and running** on firebase hosting service.

**Above answer is to clear Concept**, Provide more details of your app and structure for further help.

Comment: I get your concept but I m not sure what do i need to put in "public".  I have tried to put serval paths in there but the error is still coming up. Is that any file required in that path?

Comment: in IOS app, I have no idea what are you trying to host. IOS SDK just should be used to create/read/update/remove firebase data.

Comment: Omg, I was misunderstood the hosting part. i thought firebase need me to set up the hosting for storing firebase data

Comment: Is that mean if i am building an ios app i can ignore the hosting part right and do all the security and rules in dashboard?

Comment: Yes- hosting is needed only when you develop website and want to host it. In IOS app you need CRUD only see dashboard and explore it.

Comment: If you're trying to use the Firebase command line tools to just deploy your security rules, you can also run `firebase deploy:rules`. That removes the need for a `public/index.html`.

Answer (score -2):

what are you building your app with?
I imagine the cause of the error is that you need to generate a 'dist' folder for your app and you haven't done that yet before running 'firebase deploy'.
Check the firebase.json file in your project directory, it will show you that Firebase is looking for a dist folder to read from.
IF it can't find it, you will get the error that you have.

For instance, if it is an Angular2 application and you use the Angular-cli, just do the following:

1. Run the command 'ng build' in your project's root directory.
   This command will generate a 'dist' folder from the 'src' folder where you wrote your application code.
2. Then run '
   firebase deploy'.